# PhoneGap BlackBerry / Webworks Build Error

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I have used the command line tools provided in PhoneGap 2.7.0 to create a BlackBerry 7 and earlier project that uses the WebWorks SDK.  During the build process, the build scripts try to execute the bbwp.exe tool provided in the webworks sdk to compile the zip file for BB.  The issue is that when bbwp.exe is executed, it gives this error (which I can replicate outside the PhoneGap build scripts)

> C:\Apps\BlackBerryWebWorksSDK>bbwp.exe "C:\PlayGround\PhoneGapTest\BlackBerryHello\build\BlackBerryHelloWorld.zip"
>
> [INFO]                  Parsing command line options
>
> [INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
>
> [INFO]                  Validating application archive
>
> [INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
>
> [INFO]                  Populating application source
>
> [INFO]                  Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application
> I/O Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
> [ERROR]                 RAPC exception occurred

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have JDK\bin (correct version) first in your path:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;...

This resolved the error for me. Moving to the next error :|

note: I also use the elided path (sans spaces), just in case. some tools are still problematic with spaces in directories.